Errores al crear exe pyinstaller (onefile) dentro de virtualenv
¡Que tal!
Estoy aprendiendo a crear ejecutables con pyinstaller, pero me salían con muchísimo peso para el programa que es, de aproximadamente 400 MB.
Estuve investigando que es porque pyinstaller incluye todas las librerías instaladas, se usen o no, y que es peor al trabajar con Pandas y Anaconda. Mi código justo usa Pandas y trabajo sobre Anaconda.
También leí que una solución podía ser usar un virtualenv. Lo instalé y logré ejecutar el script de python dentro del ambiente virtual, pero al momento de generar el exe con pyinstaller dentro del environment virtual, en primer lugar me manda Warnings de Conda durante el proceso. No entiendo por qué, ya que se supone que el environment ya incluye lo necesario, incluso corrí el script desde dentro del environment con Python codigo.py y no desde Anaconda Prompt como siempre lo ejecuto, y todo bien.
Y lo que yo creo que es más importante, me manda muchos mensajes de "missing module named... etc.". ¡Muchísimos! ¿Es todo lo que estoy quitando al usar el virtualenv?
De cualquier forma sí generó un exe, pero al abrirlo, me mandó primero que necesitaba una librería 'platformdirs'.

Luego de instalar tal librería dentro del environment, y volver a generar el exe con pyinstaller, me mandó otro error: "DLL load failed while importing _ctypes".

¿Me podrían orientar por favor sobre lo que necesito entender para arreglar esto?
Cabe mencionar que mi programa también usa tkinter y le añado solamente un ícono como medio externo, el cual llamo mediante
root.iconbitmap(ospath.join(ospath.dirname(__file__),r'icons\xxxx.ico')). Fuera de eso, no utilizo medios externos.
¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Continué haciendo pruebas con los virtual environments, y una de ellas fue ejecutar venv desde Python directamente (Python instalado en Windows), en lugar de ejecutarlo desde el símbolo del sistema de Anaconda. Con eso, generé el entorno virtual, dentro instalé lo que necesitaba y durante el proceso de generación del ejecutable exe, dejé de tener warnings de Conda.
Además ejecuté auto-py-to-exe en lugar de pyinstaller. Mucho más sencillo ya que abre una interfaz gráfica y te permite seleccionar los detalles de tu output.
Realmente sigo sin saber por qué si era un entorno virtual supuestamente limpio, Conda me mandaba tantos warnings. Supongo que crear un ambiente virtual desde Python directamente, genera un entorno virtual aún más limpio. Mi archivo al final pesa solo 36 MB. Posiblemente lo puedo optimizar aún más, pero se me hace muchísimo más razonable ese peso.
Logré resolver el problema, pero de cualquier manera sigo a la escucha, por si alguien me puede orientar un poco más. De igual forma si puedo ayudar a alguien con mi poca experiencia, no duden en acercarse.
¡Gracias!
